# Please help me to parse text from xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my xml:

```
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

And I want to use xslt parse this to text, a result look like this:

```
Empire Burlesque, Hide your heart, Greatest Hits, 1985, 1988, 1982,
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you can simply do

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="//cd/title, //cd/year" separator=", "/>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1.0 you can use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//cd/title">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1>, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="//cd/year">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1>, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```